# whats does the ESP-01S LED indicate

Tags: arduino, led, datasheet, esp8266

I recently bought an ESP-01S module and it only has one blue LED on it (unlike the other ESP8266 modules) and when I connect the 3v3 and gnd, it blinks twice.

I was wondering what does this LED indicate? is it only power? or maybe connected to the RX and TX pins?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a complete schematic of the board or a detailed datasheet. The only datasheet I found was [this](http://www.microchip.ua/wireless/esp01.pdf) which didn't include details.

Also, when I tried to power the ESP up, I noticed that the wires spark when I try to connect the 3v3; Does that mean I'm not supplying the module correctly? I'm using the 3v3 and the GND pin on arudino Due

Comment: this is an absolutely confusing statement `I noticed that the voltage jumps between my wire and the pins (the click sound)` .... what does all of that mean?

Comment: There are several (maybe many) versions of the ESP-01 board made by a variety of suppliers. Without a datasheet for your specific board one can only guess what the LED is doing. In the future, looks for sources that provide good documentation.

Comment: @jsotola sorry my english is awful but you see some blue line like in a tesla coil or in thunderstorms? the blue visible electricity

Comment: @ElliotAlderson as I mentioned, I searched a lot but there aren't specific datasheets out there for the ESP8266. Even the one datasheet I found didn't explain that.

Comment: @ParsaShowkati, your english is fine ... just that description was confusing ... never make live connections ... always turn off power, make connections or disconnections, then turn on power .... electric arc happens if you are connecting or disconnecting high current connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The led is connected to GPIO2/UART1_TXD as seen in the Chinese datasheet https://docs.ai-thinker.com/_media/esp8266/docs/esp-01s_product_specification_zh_v1.0.pdf

[image]

It flashes on power on because like all esps the gpio2 is toggled during boot.